# Can an external program know the number of goroutine in the go program?

Tags: go, goroutine

I can get the value through this 
`"runtime.NumGoroutine()"`..

Can I know the number of goroutines in an external program?

Comment: The classic way is to write it to a file and have the external program read that file.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry about the inaccuracy of the questionㅠㅠ 
I want to get the value of the running process without changing the source code.

Comment: That's what metrics collection libraries are for (like `github.com/uber-go/tally` and similar). But those need to be integrated into your product ahead of time.

Comment: It can't be without changing the source code since goroutine is completely a specific term in Go which is separated from operating system. But you could expose go profiling API to get the number externally.

Comment: @oakad you don't need a third-party library for that, that's what https://golang.org/pkg/expvar/ is for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you can use [`delve`](https://github.com/derekparker/delve).

1. `go get github.com/derekparker/delve/cmd/dlv`
2. run your main application
3. find the `$pid` of your main applicaiton
4. `dlv attach $pid`, then type `goroutines` to see all go routines like follows:

```
C:\work\gowork>dlv attach 5696
Type 'help' for list of commands.
(dlv) goroutines
[5 goroutines]
  Goroutine 1 - User: C:/devsoft/Go/src/runtime/time.go:102 time.Sleep (0x440c3b)
  Goroutine 2 - User: C:/devsoft/Go/src/runtime/proc.go:292 runtime.gopark (0x42a03f)
  Goroutine 3 - User: C:/devsoft/Go/src/runtime/proc.go:292 runtime.gopark (0x42a03f)
  Goroutine 17 - User: C:/devsoft/Go/src/runtime/proc.go:292 runtime.gopark (0x42a03f)
* Goroutine 19 - User: :0 ??? (0x7fffef855427) (thread 15260)
(dlv)
```

Then, what your program needs to do is to control the command `dlv` using something like `expect` to control the debug tool to input `goroutines` command.

Seems it has a xml-rpc like api for client to get more infomation, you may can have a look, I did not use the api before.

Just a thought, FYI.

Comment: Please don't include screen shots of text. Just copy and paste the text directly into the answer.